# What syntax could i use to padd spaces with different characters in this example?

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I have found this piece of code from another user on CodeWars after resolving some exercise, where he used format function.

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    round = lambda x: min(255, max(x, 0))
    return ("{:02X}" * 3).format(round(r), round(g), round(b))
```

But after few tries and searching about string formating i still dont understand how could i (if i wanted to use something simillar in future) switch '0' for some different character in this part of code "{:02X}"

When i tried to use different number than zero i of course got just more spaces, when i tried some other characters than numbers i got an error.

Answer (score 0):

What this does is repeat `{:02X}` 3 times

```py
("{:02X}" * 3)
```

So format actually sees this:

```py
("{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}")
```

Now, `:02X` means:

- `X` hexadecimal formatting
- `02` 2 characters minimum, with 0 as padding
- `:` is placeholder for values (you could also use `0:` to forcefully grab the first argument so `{1:02X}{0:02X}{2:02X}` would actually print grb instead of rgb)

if you want to pad with something else you need to change the format, for example:

```py
def rgb(r, g, b):
    round = lambda x: min(255, max(x, 0))
    return ("{: <16}" * 3).format(round(r), round(g), round(b))

print(rgb(12,255,2))
```

outputs

`12              255             2`

the number aligned to the `<` left.

If you want to maintain the hexadecimal formatting you would use `{: >16X}`